# Using simple logic instead of the thermoelectric series

Tags: electric-current, thermoelectricity

**A thermocouple is made from two metals, Antimony and Bismuth. If one junction of the couple is kept hot and the other is kept cold then, an electric current will**

The answer is - **Flow from Antimony to bismuth at cold junction.**

My logic was that, as Bismuth has a bigger atomic radius that Antimony, it will be easier for Bismuth to lose electrons.

And as the electron leave Bismuth at the hot junction *flow is at hot juction*

Both my answers are wrong, please help me understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with atomic radius, but rather with temperature gradient itself. The temperature difference at junctions, forces free electrons to diffuse from hot junction to the cold one, thus inducing electron drift speed. And if something makes charge carries to drift,- it makes a current as per :
$$ \mathbf {J} =\rho \mathbf {u} $$
Where $J$ is current density, $\rho$ charge density and $u$ - drift velocity (due to diffusion by temperature gradient *this time*)